# Can I use ApplicationContext to log events instead of Activity context for facebook app events?

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am using facebook sdk to track app installs and log events.I have 4 activities in my app. According to the documentation, I am activating and deactivating in every activity.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

 private FacebookSingleton fb = FacebookSingleton.getInstance();

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   //some event occurred
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("SEARCH QUERY", query);
    fb.trackEventForFb("PRODUCT SEARCH", params);
 }

 @Override
   protected void onResume() { 
   super.onResume(); 
   AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this); 
 }

 @Override
   protected void onPause() { 
   super.onPause(); 
   AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
}



public class FacebookSingleton {

private static MyApplication appInstance;
private static FacebookSingleton instance;

private FacebookSingleton() {
 };
public static void setupFb(MyApplication myAppInstance) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new FacebookSingleton();
        appInstance = myAppInstance;
    }
}

public void trackFacebookEvent(String event,Bundle parameters) {
    AppEventsLogger logger = AppEventsLogger.newLogger(appInstance);
    logger.logEvent(event, parameters);
}
```

And this is my application

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    FacebookSingleton.setupFb(this);

 }
}
```

When I log events, can I create a singleton and pass that context instead of using activity context to log events like the code aboce? Or do I need to pass the activity context only according to the documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work, but you may not get the full information. For certain events we will try to get things like the Activity name from the context. It's guarded so that if the Context is not an Activity, it will not fail, but you may not get the full information passed along.